# Prereqisites for: Subsystems of second order arithmetic

Tags: logic, computability, foundations, proof-theory

As the title suggests, im wondering what the prerequisites for Simpsons book, Subsystems of... are?
Unfortunately I cant find it in the preface.

My background is a Bachelor in Philosophy and Mathematics. I heard a course on mathematical logic (completeness incompleteness) and wrote my thesis about Model Theory and Set Theory, however my background in Proof and Recusrion theory is just the very basics, needed for a first course in logic.
Which would be adequate books on Proof and Recursion theory to be fit for Simpsons work?

Comment: I think that a "standard" textbook will be enough: Joseph Shoenfield, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=a9zuAAAAMAAJ) (1967) or the "classic" S.C.Kleene, [INtroduction to Metamathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=HZAjPwAACAAJ) (1952).

Comment: But you can take benefit also of: Stephen Simpson, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf) (2013), Stephen Simpson, [Model Theory](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/master.pdf) (1998) and Stephen Simpson, [Foundations of Mathematics](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/fom.pdf) (2009).

Comment: Incidentally, I would recommend Denis Hirschfeldt's recent book "Slicing the truth" instead of Subsystems - it's much better for self-study (although Simpson's book is an incredible reference).